# product page error in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, product, admin, admin-panel

I am unable to view details of products in admin panel. I got this below error, how to resolve this error?
[image]

Comment: did you disabled the extension marketplace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you uninstall markeplace extension? After that, delete the database record that causes a conflict with the following statement:

```
DELETE FROM eav_attribute 
WHERE attribute_code = 'seller_id';
```

Comment: no its not working

Comment: DELETE FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'seller_id';

Comment: u r awesome @rashmism